# How to pass the parameters to WCF Web Service with special characters?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I'm using WCF with C#.

I have to pass the parameters to WCF web service with special characters like-
Email-ram@gmail.com and Password-Test@123

While passing the parameters, got error "404 Not Found" and if passed parameters without special characters it's working.

**Working**

```
localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/LoginRequest/ram/Test123/1223
```

**Not Working**

```
localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/LoginRequest/ram@gmail.com/Test@123/1223
```

Is it possible?

```
/** Code for the same **/
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke( 
    Method = "POST", 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
    UriTemplate = "LoginRequest/{Email}/{Password}/{APPUID}")]

string LoginRequest(string Email, string Password, string APPUID);

public string LoginRequest(string Email, string Password, string APPUID)
{
    string strResult = "";
    if (Password.Trim() != null && Password.Trim() != "" && Email.Trim() != null && Email.Trim() != "")
        {
            strResult = " Success.";
        }
    else
        {
            strResult = "User name and password are required.";
        }
    return strResult;
}
```

Comment: you'll need to `HTMLEncode` these chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send the parts that are parameters through [Html encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388364.aspx):

```
var safeEmailParam = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(yourEMailParam);
```

Comment: After doing the same, I got the error 405 Method Not Allowed.

Comment: @RamBodake We cannot guess what you may have done. Post your code.

Comment: **This is Operation Contract-**
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            UriTemplate = "LoginRequest/{Email}/{Password}/{APPUID}")]
        string LoginRequest(string Email, string Password, string APPUID);

Comment: @RamBodake Please edit your original question and post a [mcve].

Comment: **LoginRequest Method as below-**
public string LoginRequest(string Email, string Password, string APPUID)
        {
           string strResult = "";
            if (Password.Trim() != null && Password.Trim() != "" && Email.Trim() != null && Email.Trim() != "")
            {               
                    strResult = " Success.";
            }
            else
            {
                strResult = "User name and password are required.";
            }
            return strResult;
        }

Comment: @RamBodake Where do you use `WebUtility.HtmlEncode` in your code?

Comment: While I'm sending I'd converted it and **URL** like this-
localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/LoginRequest/rambodake18%40gmail.com.com/Test%40123/Test

Answer (score 0):

check **CDATA** below link hope it helps

[CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)

Comment: **How to use this?**

Comment: check this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean